# Suggest queries in spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch not working

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, autocomplete, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to execute a suggest query using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch. While a term query like this:

`@Query(value = "{\"term\" : { \"questionElasticSearch\" : \"?0\" }}")
List<QuestionElasticSearch> getSuggestions2(String questionElasticSearch);`

is working, a suggest query like this:

`@Query("{\"suggest\": {\"song-suggest\" : {\"prefix\" : \"?0\",\"completion\" : {\"field\" : \"questionElasticSearch\"}}}}")
List<QuestionElasticSearch> getSuggestions(String questionElasticSearch);`

is not. Leaving away the "suggest" and "song-suggest" still gives an error. Getting:

org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: no [query] registered for [suggest]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.parseInnerQueryBuilder(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:337) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.WrapperQueryBuilder.doRewrite(WrapperQueryBuilder.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.rewrite(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:284) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.rewrite(SearchSourceBuilder.java:949) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.rewrite(SearchSourceBuilder.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.Rewriteable.rewriteAndFetch(Rewriteable.java:97) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.Rewriteable.rewriteAndFetch(Rewriteable.java:87) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:216) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:139) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some basic support in Spring Data Elasticsearch for the correct mapping and indexing of completion fields by defining a field of a `@Document` annotated class being of type `Completion`.

But the support for querying is only existing in the `ElasticsearchTemplate` class which uses the `TransportClient`, which is deprecated as of Elasticsearch 7.0 and will be removed in 8, and therefore will also be removed from Spring Data Elasticsearch when the supported version of ES changes to 8 (should be in 5.x probably). 
This basic implementation was never added to the `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` class and is missing as well from the `ElasticsearchRepository` implementations - and that leads to the errors you see.

So you can use Spring Data Elasticsearch to store data in the desired format, but cannot query it. I created [a Jira issue for this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-622).